# `onNotificationOpened` not being called when app is killed or removed from memory for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, react-native, onesignal

I went thru the documentation on GitHub, and understand that there is a small issue with iOS and OneSignal for ReactNative, where the notification is coming too fast.  But here my issue is that i believe the callback `onNotification` is not being called when the app isn't in the background.

```
OneSignal.configure({
  onNotificationOpened: function(message, data, isActive) {
  var notification = {message: message, data: data, isActive: isActive};
  alert("going to handleNotification");
  handleNotification(notification);
  }
});
```

This is the snipped of code that is supposed to run as a callback for when a notification is opened.  It runs perfectly fine when the app is opened and in the background.

But lets say I kill the app by double clicking the home button and removing the app.  Then when a notification comes in and I click on it, I do not get the alert.  This leads me to the conclusion that the call back is not being called.  The app opens up fine, but that the payload in the notification isn't loaded because the method `handleNotification` isn't called.

ReactNative 0.29

OS: iOS 9.3

Any thoughts/ideas/solutions would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is kinda stupid on OneSignal part, considering the [documentations](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4egzDMGQLDQJ:https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/common-problems-1%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) clearly whats below, however, without google cache you get a lovely [404 error](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/common-problems-1)

> In order for notifications with buttons to display the following must be true:
>
> 1. You can not force close the app by double tapping the home button and swiping away your app.
>
>    If this is the case you will see an entry in the device log in Xcode like the following.
>      apsd[83] : Low Priority Push: com.onesignal.example - App killed
> 2. Go to Settings>General>"Background App Refresh" and mke sure it is enable for both the device and your app.
>      [image]
> 3. Make sure "Remote notifications" are checked under Capabilities>Background Modes shown in step 2. Add Required Capabilities. Note: This is automatic for some plugins like Cordova and Corona.